Why does setting dotnets HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion not apply to the HttpClient.SendAsync method
This is purely to assist in understanding the design choices of dotnets HttpClient class.
Backstory, we were dealing with a Load Balancer that did not support HTTP/1.* requests. Not a problem we attempted to bump the HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion to HTTP/2.0 with HttpClient.DefaultVersionPolicy set to HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionOrLower, expecting this would be enough for the HttpClient to start sending HTTP/2.0 requests (and fall back to HTTP/1.1 when that was not possible).
However we quickly noted that settings these defaults for the HttpClient across the entire application for the HttpClient appeared to have no effect (there are obviously arguments for why one might not want to do this, however please see past that xD).
In the dotnet docs for the HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion, there is a remarks section stating:

The DefaultRequestVersion property doesn't apply to the SendAsync
method. The HttpRequestMessage parameter passed as the argument to the
SendAsync method has its own Version property that controls the HTTP
version used for the request.

Can anyone shed some light around this design decision, it seems a little counter intuitive? Is it purely dotnets SoC (the thing that sends the message, and the message itself are two separate concerns, but then why offer the HttpClient... settings if that was the case)

Do you always use .SendAsync for everything? If you use the other methods, such as .GetAsync, .GetStringAsync, etc. how do you control the version?

No, however in this particular case we were using SendAsync.

@ProgrammingLlama
Ahhhhhh I see now, there are the GetAsync, PostAsync, PutAsync etc methods, which likely use the HttpClient settings. However SendAsync allows for more control, you can define the request (in its entirety dynamically), instead of being forced into a particular method.
Now the question with "do we use SendAsync for everything" makes more sense.
Thank you :)

SendAsync is the method through which all actual requests are dispatched; all the other HttpClient methods are basically wrappers around that one. That said, it is odd to me that SendAsync completely ignores DefaultVersion; I would instead expect it to use that value if set, unless HttpRequestMessage.Version was also explicitly set, in which case it should use the latter.
